# Why do these javascript regex throw syntax errors?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a text string as a date before processing it, however both of the regex i have tried are throwing syntax errors and I can't see why. From what I can tell there is nothing wrong with either. These are the strings:

```
 var datePattern1 = new RegExp( (0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](19|20)\d\d );
```

and

```
var datePattern2 = new RegExp( [0-3][0-9]-(0|1)[0-9]-(19|20)[0-9]{2} );
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 12):

You are missing the quotes around your expressions:

```
var datePattern1 = new RegExp( "(0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](19|20)\d\d" );
var datePattern2 = new RegExp( "[0-3][0-9]-(0|1)[0-9]-(19|20)[0-9]{2}" );
```

Comment: is it really as simple as that? doh

Comment: No, it's not that simple. Also the \d\d at the end has to be \\d\\d.

Answer (score 9):

Either pass a string to the `RegExp` constructor as darin mentioned or use the RegExp syntax “`/ … /`”:

```
var datePattern1 = /(0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-](19|20)\d\d/;
var datePattern2 = /[0-3][0-9]-(0|1)[0-9]-(19|20)[0-9]{2}/;
```

Answer (score 3):

The Regexp() constructor expects a string, so you need to quote your regex:

```
var datePattern2 = new RegExp('[0-3][0-9]-(0|1)[0-9]-(19|20)[0-9]{2}');
```

When using double quotes, watch out for backslash escapes in the regex. Alternatively, you can use the Perl syntax:

```
var datePattern2 = /[0-3][0-9]-(0|1)[0-9]-(19|20)[0-9]{2}/;
```

Comment: if you use the perl syntax do you then pass the var to the regex constructor?

Comment: No. The slash syntax is a "regex literal." No need to create a Regex object around it.